# Moving data from linked list to queue [c]

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

So I am a self learner and I am stuck here. What I want to accomplish is create a linked list with some data, then pick a random node from the linked list, change some data and then move it to a queue(the queue is implemented using linked list as well)

I am not sure how to write my structs too. Here are my structs.

```
struct Apps{
    int id;
    int size;
    char name;
    float xronos_eiswdou;
    char condition;
    int xronos_ekteleshs;
    struct Apps *next, *next1;
}*rear, *front;
```

I am sure it is wrong and I don't have a clue on how to fix it.

This is my function as of now.

```
void push(struct Apps *head)
{
     struct Apps *temp; 
     struct Apps *temp1;
     temp1=(struct Apps *)malloc(sizeof(struct Apps));
     temp1->id = temp->id;
     temp1->size = temp->size;
     temp1->name = temp->name;
     temp1->xronos_eiswdou = temp->xronos_eiswdou;
     temp1->condition = temp->condition;
     temp1->xronos_ekteleshs = temp->xronos_ekteleshs;
     temp1->next = head;
     if (front == NULL)
     {
           front=temp1;
           front->next1=NULL;
           rear=front;
     }
     else
     {
           front->next1=temp1;
           front=temp1;
           front->next1=NULL;
     }
}
```

Here is my main code for adding data to my linked list:

```
for(step = 0; step < 100; step++)
      {
        int r = rand() % 100+1;
        if(r < 31){
            int r1 = rand() % 100+1;
            aa = r1;
            int r2 = rand() % 100+1;
            bb = r2;
            int r3 = rand() % 3;
            if(r3 == 0){ 
                 cc = 'l';
            }
            else if(r3 == 1 ){ 
                 cc = 'b';
            }
            else if( r3 == 2 ){ 
                 cc = 'c';
            }
            dd = (double)seconds/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            ee = 'a';
            ff = -1;
            insert_new(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff);
        }
        else if(r > 30 && r < 51){
            pickRandom(head); /*picking a random node and changing some data*/
            /*Here I need a function which moves the data of the above node to a queue*/
        }
    }
```

Long story short, I need a function which moves data from a linked list to a queue! Any help is appreciated and excuse my question, I am learning stuff by myself :/

**EDIT**

I tried something which seems to work, well kind off...
Here are my structures:

```
    struct Apps{
    int id;
    int size;
    char name;
    float xronos_eiswdou;
    char condition;
    int xronos_ekteleshs;
    struct Apps *next;
};

struct Queue
{
    int id1;
    int size1;
    char name1;
    float xronos_eiswdou1;
    char condition1;
    int xronos_ekteleshs1;
    struct Queue *next;
    struct Queue *front;
    struct Queue *rear;
};
```

and here is my function:

```
struct Queue *start = NULL;
struct Queue *front = NULL;
struct Queue *rear = NULL;

    void push()
    {
         struct Apps *temp; 
         struct Queue *temp1;
         temp1=(struct Queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
         temp1->id1 = temp->id; 
         temp1->size1 = temp->size;
         temp1->name1 = temp->name;
         temp1->xronos_eiswdou1 = temp->xronos_eiswdou;
         temp1->condition1 = temp->condition;
         temp1->xronos_ekteleshs1 = temp->xronos_ekteleshs;
         temp1->next = start;
         if (front == NULL)
         {
               front=temp1;
               front->next=NULL;
               rear=front;
         }
         else
         {
               front->next=temp1;
               front=temp1;
               front->next=NULL;
         }
}
```

The program runs with no errors but it crashes, so it's something wrong again!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you really should format your code according to one of the standards, for example like in your C textbook. Your code is difficult to read.

Comment: Fist implement the functionality to delete a node - you have to alter the `next` pointer in the *previous* item in the list to the deleted node's `next` pointer.  When you have done that then (with the `insert`) you have the components in place.  Do one step at a time.

Comment: @cdarke i want to move the data to a queue's node and then remove the node from the list. That is what i don't understand

Comment: I think he is trying to move the node which is of type (Apps) to his queue (Queue_struct)

Comment: ie; He is trying to collect the modified `Apps` node in a queue it seems...

Comment: "Linked list" describes a data structure.  "Queue", on the other hand, mostly describes the *manner of use* of a data structure.

Comment: Can you please share the original problem or scenario which you are trying to achieve with this datastructure?

Comment: Since your queue is implemented via a linked list, why do you need separate, parallel structures for list and queue elements?

Comment: One is to maintain original data and another is to collect the modified content it seems..

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian "I think he is trying to move the node which is of type (Apps) to his queue (Queue_struct)" This is what i want to do. I have created a linked list with several nodes(the number is random). What i want is pick a random node(already done that) and move it to my queue

Comment: I tried doing it with one struct. Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is

1.A list contains some random number of nodes

2.Have to collect the elements modified in the list in a queue (which is another list)

To solve this please modify your structure as,

```
 struct Apps{
    int id;
    int size;
    char name;
    float xronos_eiswdou;
    char condition;
    int xronos_ekteleshs;
    struct Apps *next;
};

struct Queue
{
    Struct Apps *node;
    struct Queue * next;
};
```

So, now you will be having the original list of elements in the list (Apps) and the modified nodes (of Apps list) collected in the queue (Queue_struct) which is implemented with `LinkedList`.

Comment: ok, done this... my other problem is that I cant understand how to write the function which moves the modified nodes in the queue

Comment: super.. then please try with this and let me know if you face any trouble while implementing..

Comment: I tried something but it crashes when i run it. There are no compilation errors though. Can you please check out my edit in my questions?

Comment: you have a variable `temp` (struct Apps *temp; ) which you have neither alloted some memory for it not initialized with some value but you tried to fetch value from it which would have raised to some erroneous situation...